# How to display limit per page using foreach in mvc 4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i have a foreach in my view it will fetch data from database as per request.

i need to display 10 result per page. what i mean is i have to diplay 10 result in div 1 , and another 10 result in div 2.. is this possible to do.  how to do this. or if u have any other idea related to this share with me.. thanks

My view code:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    if (Model.Count() != 0)
    {
        <div class="">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="tiptext">
                    <b style="margin-left: 0px; font-size: large;color: #1A0DB2;">@item.BusinessName</b>
                    <h3 style="margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;color: rgb(0, 145, 0);"> @item.FirstName</h3>
                    <h3 style="margin: 8px; color:black">@item.BusinessCategory </h3>
                    <div class="description">
                        <div class="description_image">
                            <img src="~/Images/popup_pointer.jpg" />
                            <div class="POP_UP_outer">
                                <div class="description_background">
                                    <div class="description_map">
                                        <b>Map</b>

                                    </div><hr />
                                    <div class="description_body">
                                        <b>Description </b><h4 class="des">@item.BusinessDescription</h4>
                                        <b>Address2 </b><h4 class="des">@item.Address1</h4>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <label id="lblErrorMsg" title="Record not fount...!" style="color:red;">Record not found...!</label>
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to have 10 items and then a 'next' button to call a server method that returns the next 10 items, or do you want to display all (say) 30 items in 3 separate divs?

Comment: 1st it should fetch 30 items to server to client then it display 10 items per page( in div)..next' button next div 10 items continues..

Comment: Suggest you start with [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, you can simply use `Take()`. Then you can figure out your paging strategy:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Take(10))
{
}
```

This will take the first 10 of that list. You can mix it with `Skip()` if you need to.

Comment: IS this possible to implement in web grid ??

Comment: Skip can precede a take, so : `Model.Skip(10).Take(10)`. I would use variables instead of hard coded values to get what you want.